# User properties, random object without concord .. Why doesn't works? Why doesn't get 21 objects?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, request, backendless

I have a complex problem, what I don't understand. In this class I would like to
add 21 random objects from one arraylist listChallenges to the arraylist finalChallenges. However it doesn't work , sometimes finalChallanges contains 21 objects , but most of the times it contains less objects, but I don't know where is the problem. Actually, I tried to comment every step, and if did something wrong, please tell me. 
Please help me, I have no idea what shoud I do..

```
 ArrayList<Challenges>          listChallenges  = new ArrayList<Challenges>();
 ArrayList<Challenges>          finalChallenges = new ArrayList<Challenges>(20);

//Check where the same userId and subscribers.objectId,
    //Request these categories object and save to the  ArrayList<Category> totalCategories
    //Save these categories objectId to the selectedCategoriesId List<String>
    BackendlessDataQuery query = new BackendlessDataQuery();
    query.setWhereClause( "subscribers.objectId = '"+backendlessUser.getObjectId()+"'");

    Backendless.Data.of(Category.class).find(query, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Category>>() {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Category> categoriesBackendlessCollection) {
            //add selected categories to totalActivities Category ArrayList
            for( Category categories : categoriesBackendlessCollection.getData()) {
                totalCategories.add(categories);
                selectedCategoriesId.add(categories.getObjectId());
               //
            }
            System.out.println(selectedCategoriesId);

            //For cycle is going to selectedCategoriesId.size
            //Check where the same category-objectId and actual selectedCategoriesId
            //Request these challenges object, which are in the actual category and save to the  ArrayList<Challenges> listChallenges
            //Save these categories objectId to the selectedCategoriesId List<String>
            for(int k=0;k<selectedCategoriesId.size();k++) {

                BackendlessDataQuery query = new BackendlessDataQuery();
                query.setPageSize(pageSize);
                query.setWhereClause("category.objectId = '" + selectedCategoriesId.get(k) + "'");

                Backendless.Data.of(Challenges.class).find(query, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Challenges>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Challenges> cha) {
                        for (Challenges challenges : cha.getData()) {
                            listChallenges.add(challenges);

                            challengeTitle.add(challenges.getChallengeTitle());
                            challengeContent.add(challenges.getChallengeContent());
                            challangeId.add(challenges.getObjectId());
                        }
                        System.out.println("osszes elem:"+listChallenges);
                        //ArrayList<Challenges> finalChallenges  size is 21 with 0
                        //  get from listChallenges random 21 object without concord and add to the finalChallenges
                        Random random = new Random();
                        List<Challenges> temp = new ArrayList<>(listChallenges);
                        ArrayList<Challenges> tempNewList = new ArrayList<Challenges>();
                        //ArrayList<Challenges> temp = new ArrayList<Challenges>(listChallenges.size());
                        for (Challenges item : listChallenges) temp.add(item);
                        while (finalChallenges.size()<21 && temp.size()>0) {
                               int index = random.nextInt(temp.size());
                               tempNewList.add(temp.get(index));
                               temp.remove(index);
                            finalChallenges= tempNewList;
                        }

                       // System.out.println("kihívások");
                        System.out.println(finalChallenges);
                        System.out.println(finalChallenges.size());

                       // title.setText(challengeTitle.get(0));
                       // content.setText(challengeContent.get(0));
                       // objectId = challangeId.get(0);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

                    }
                });

                //save finalChallenges array objects to the current user "userChallenges" relationship
                Backendless.UserService.login( email, password, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser backendlessUser) {

                        backendlessUser.setProperty("userChallenges",new ArrayList<>(finalChallenges));


                            }
                        });

                        Backendless.UserService.update(backendlessUser, new BackendlessCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser response) {
                                System.out.println( "User has been updated" );
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                                System.out.println( "User has not been updated");
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
                        System.out.println( "Server reported an error - " + backendlessFault.getMessage() );
                    }
                },true);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show where `finalChallenges` is initialized, and we can see it is overwritten asynchronously in response handlers: it is very likely an issue of concurrent access.

The logic itself where you fill the list from random elements of another list would be correct, if the instance of `finalChallenges` was not "shared" across different/concurrent executions of that handler.

Also, a small tip: to create your temp list in one go without loop you can do this: `List<Challenge> temp = new ArrayList<>(listChallenges);`

Edit: 2 suggestions.

1. Use a temporary list in your loop when you fill it, then swap the lists **atomically** (`listChallenges = tempNewList`)
2. When you pass your list to user properties, **pass a copy** (`backendlessUser.setProperty("userChallenges", new ArrayList<>(finalChallenges));`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited. Actually it works very well,i going to accept your answer, but can you help me why set user properties less object? For example the finalCHallenges conatins 21 and the properties add just 12 , ? If you could help I will be greatfull

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. It's very late here, I have to leave for now, but tomorrow I can offer to explain the issue in better details if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much , I edited the code in the question how looks like now.

Comment: Edited for a second suggestion. I did not see initially you pass the list to update server-side. I suppose this is also handled asynchronously.

Comment: Thank your help, you are very helpfull... The update method updating from server-side. Actually, I had noticed that, the listChallenges doesn't contain all objects, while selectedCategoriesId is fine.. and for this reason uccors the problems hmm